# I want to create two text fields on screen first textfield should be defined size and second's height should be equals to remaining screen space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I  want to achieve an layout in flutter in which first textfield is of defined height let suppose 16, and second textfield should cover all remaining space just like shown in the picture

[image: Question]

Now  I have achieved this layout by wrapping textfield in expanded and giving it height of the screen and because of expanded widget it won't overflow. I know this is the bad approach but problem is when I start writing in textfield it starts writing on the bottom of textfield. Now if it is textfield or other widget in the picture which hint text is **What's it for?**. All in all how can I achieve this type of layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you mind try

```
       Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Test"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(height: 16, child: TextField()),
            Expanded(
                child: TextField(
              expands: true,
              minLines: null,
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "What's it for?"),
            ))
          ],
        )
```

Comment: half of the problem is solved but you can see in image hint text is written on topleft corner and when I write it also starts from topleft corner but in your solution although size issue resolved but text is being written in the middle of the screen

Comment: Thanks very much I figured it out by adding this line it resolved my problem `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top`